# Stop LaTeX from breaking an inline math equation

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, inline

I hope this question was not asked before. At least I haven't found it. I have an inline math equation and LaTeX is breaking it into two parts. In this case I'd prefer to have the whole and short equation in one line. Is there any way I can do that? I already tried to put it into a `\mbox` but that destroyed the whole layout. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here $v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}$.
\end{document}
```

Here the result would be:

```
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts but is not wanted right here v_{initial} =
1000m/s.
```

Comment: Did you try `\hbox`'ing the math?

Comment: @Joseph Wright, the result is the same like with `\mbox`. You get an overfull box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent LaTeX from breaking inline formulas globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/how-can-i-prevent-latex-from-breaking-inline-formulas-globally)

Comment: I would vote not to close this question but the newer one with the lower score.

Comment: I don't think these two are duplicates, as the other is global and this is about a single formula.

Comment: @cabohah [The duplicate target should be the one with better answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/349538), and since in my opinion the top answer to the other question is better, I flagged this one as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Reading only the top answer IMHO is not a good idea.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Put the math expression into braces `{...}`, then it will be a math atom and not broken at the end of the line.

```
${v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}}$
```

to prevent an overfull box use `\sloppy` or better the `sloppypar` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sloppypar}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here ${v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}}$.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. But LaTeX is splitting it for good reason, maybe I'm going to re-arrange the sentence.

Comment: The sloppypar is cool!

Comment: Note that, depending on your exact situation, enclosing the paragraph with `sloppypar` may be enough, without freezing the whitespace in the math environment (See @david-carlisle s answer) by using braces. So maybe try that first.

Answer (score 79):

As other answers have mentioned you may use an extra set of `{}` however this is essentially equivalent to using `\mbox{......}`  and like all such boxing does *two* things. It prevents line breaking but it also freezes all white space at its natural size and prevents stretching or shrinking, this makes it even harder to fit the unbreakable box into the paragraph.

It is usually better to prevent line breaks without freezing the white space. TeX will break after binary operators and relations and the penalty for breaking in those places are set by default in LaTeX to

```
\binoppenalty=700
\relpenalty=500
```

So if you set

```
\binoppenalty=10000 
\relpenalty=10000
```

Then Line breaking will be prevented for the rest of the document (or environment) without needing to add markup to each inline expression and allowing TeX to stretch or shrink white space to fit the expression into the surrounding paragraph.

Comment: Perhaps better than `\maxdimen` is 9999, which will avoid it as much as possible, but permit it in extreme cases. From [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/how-can-i-prevent-latex-from-breaking-inline-formulas-globally).

Comment: isnt this obviously the best answer?

Comment: @peter obviously I think so:-)

Comment: @peter Better than mine, I agree. But it wouldn't hurt to add that you can put this assignments *inside* the formula, if you wish to limit the effect to that one formula. It's the values *at the end of math mode* that counts, so put them wherever you like (but not inside a group).

Comment: Using `\maxdimen` gave me an error saying "bad mathchar 1073741823", but using `10000` worked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't use mathchar at all in my code, I tried `\maxdimen` as you suggested and I got an error related to mathchar.

Comment: @DonaldDuck i'll change the answer to 10000  :-)

Answer (score 18):

Line breaking will not occur inside a part of a formula that is enclosed in braces:

```
${v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}}$
```

Answer (score 14):

You can prevent the linebreak by using braces. But you will then get an overfull box:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here ${v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

TeX thinks an equals sign is a good place to break an inline equation. Putting \nolinebreak right after the equals sign avoids the break (you do get an overfull box, though).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply include a line break (`\\`).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here \\ $v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the first line won't be justified. (Not that it would look good if it's justified, but unjustified may be even worse.)

Answer (score 6):

If your are really sure that a linebreak before the equation is a good idea, you can do it manually:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here \linebreak $v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In contrast to the [answer of Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10851/36296), this will leave the first line justified.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on the difference between your answer and the one by Yiannis Lazarides.

Comment: Umm, are you sure that double-backslash creates a new paragraph (in the TeX sense of the word)? Incidentally, your MWE creates a horribly underfull line if compiled with the `article` instead of the `minimal` document class.

Comment: @Mico Not in the tex sense, I tried to describe the line breaking behaviour. I tried to reword it.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the above answers, because it would cause some equations to go outside the margins. My solution takes advantage of the `\( \)` LaTeX syntax, and is inspired by `\filbreak`: if it is not enough space on the line, it will print the equation on a new line. It will however leave some space: that is if it doesn't fit, it will look as if you did `\\` before the equation.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\binoppenalty=\maxdimen
\relpenalty=\maxdimen
\def\hfillbreak{\hskip 0pt plus 1fill\relax\penalty20\hskip 0pt plus -1fill}
\preto\(\hfillbreak %<- You might want this in a separate file or something
                    %   as it might affect your IDEs syntax highlighting
\begin{document}
    A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
    but is not wanted right here \( v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s} \).
    More math here \( v_{initial} = \SI{1000}{m/s} \)
\end{document}
```

It's probably possible to do it with the `$` syntax using some redefinitions and such, but I don't have time to figure it out now.

**NB** This might not cover all the special cases and such, but seems to work fine for my usecases.