# How can I prevent LaTeX from breaking inline formulas globally?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am using the `acmsmall` template and my inline formulas are being broken at equal signs and arrows; how can I prevent them from being typeset like that globally (i.e. without having to put tildes everywhere)?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/prevent-latex-to-break-an-inline-math-equation

Comment: @diabonas: Good that you found that question. But here it's about avoiding these line breaks _globally_. The answers to that other question don't address this.

Comment: I added *globally* to the title, so that is clearer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop LaTeX from breaking an inline math equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/stop-latex-from-breaking-an-inline-math-equation)

Comment: @cabohah That's the question linked in the first comment.  While the two are _related_, they are not _duplicates_ as this one is about achieving the effect **globally** and the other is about a single formula.  I would therefore not classify them as duplicates.

Comment: @AndrewStacey If you put the lines of [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94397/277964) or to the document preamble it is a global solution! See also [Andreas' adaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434869/277964) And on the other side, two of the answers below are not globally.

Comment: @cabohah Duplicate _answers_ doesn't make duplicate _questions_. With duplicates, the principle is to think about someone searching for the question afresh.  That person might well distinguish between a solution that works globally as to one that works on an individual question.  There could be a third question that clearly asks _both_ versions of the question, in which case each of these could be closed as a duplicate of _that_ (it's not uncommon for these meta-questions to be asked), but given how old these questions are then I'd leave well alone.

Comment: @AndrewStacey The other question wasn't explicitly a question for a local solution. So IMHO it is already the general question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Increase the penalty for line breaks at relation symbols and binary operators:

```
\relpenalty=9999
\binoppenalty=9999
```

If you simply include these commands in your preamble (between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`), it will prevent line breaks in most cases, but in extreme situations, they can still be broken. If you set

```
\relpenalty=10000
\binoppenalty=10000
```

equations will *never* be broken - this may, however, destroy your layout!

Comment: wonderful, that seems to have done the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 25):

`\mbox{$equation$}` is not an answer, unfortunately: the spacing in the equation doesn't grow or shrink together with the other spaces in the line. The "correct" answer is

```
$LHS=\nobreak RHS$
```

TeX will choose another break point, if there is one, or warn about an `Overfull \hbox`

Diabonas's answer shows how to avoid such breaks globally, and correctly warns about the dangers of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to simply wrap the equation within curly brackets preceded by a tilde. See the example below.

Instead of

```
$x = \{x\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R_{\ge0}}\}$
```

you would write

```
$~{x = \{x\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R_{\ge0}}\}}$
```