# Get warnings for breaking of inline math

Tags: math-mode, warnings

I have read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18298/prevent-line-breaking-in-inline-math-but-allow-flexible-spacing) about how to prevent line breaking in inline math. Now I wonder if it is possible to get a warning to the `log` for every breaking of an inline math formula.

Comment: I added an answer at the link @AlanMunn gave

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I deleted my bad advice, as is my wont.