# tufte-book marginfigure overlaps full-width content

Tags: floats, margins, tufte, marginpar, layout

```tex
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{mwe}
% avoid line breaks in inline math
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14243/
\relpenalty=9999
\binoppenalty=9999

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

Some text, but less than the height of the margin figure.

\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{The caption of the figure}
\end{marginfigure}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Another caption}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I am looking for a suggestion to avoid the overlap in the figures. I am hoping there's a solution that does not involve adding a fixed amount of vertical space, but something that would adapt to the situation where there is enough text to not require any blank vertical space.

I tried `\usepackage{marginfix}` without success.

Comment: I would be very surprised, if there was an automatic solution, so you should  compose your text carefully in order to avoid overlapping. You probably have to specify an offset with `\begin{marginfigure}[⟨offset⟩]`, cf. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

First option: place the text line inside a minipage of adequate height to keep it aligned with the figure in the margin:

```
\begin{minipage}[c][4cm][c]{\textwidth}
    Some text, but less than the height of the margin figure.
\end{minipage}
```

[image: a]

Second option: send the `figure*` to the top of the page using as float position specifier `[!]`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% avoid line breaks in inline math
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14243/
\relpenalty=9999
\binoppenalty=9999

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    
Some text, but less than the height of the margin figure.

\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{The caption of the figure}
\end{marginfigure}  

\begin{figure*}[!]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}   
    \caption{Another caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```