# Can LuaTeX do something to alter linebreaks inside math inline automatically?

Tags: line-breaking, luatex, inline

This is kind of a follow up to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/prevent-latex-to-break-an-inline-math-equation). Consider the sample code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here $v_{initial} = 11111$.
\end{document}
```

Without any modification, `TeX` splits the inline formula after the `=` sign. One can modify the code adding braces around the content of the inline math: `${v_{initial} = 11111}$`, then `TeX` does not split the formula, thus it runs in the right margin and `TeX` complains with an `overfull box`.

Now comes `LuaTeX` and its callback that can alter the paragraph building algorithm (`post_linebreak_filter`). Would it be possible to add some lua code, triggered when `TeX` enters an inline math expression, that would see that

- `11111` is "too" short to come up alone in the next line
- `v_{initial}` is not that "long" so it could be pushed to the next line without leaving "too much" blank on the line
- and that it would be worth adding some glue *before* the inline math so that the whole inline math would be at the beginning of the second line?

Comment: Just increase the value of `\relpenalty`. LaTeX sets it to 500, a larger value would make less desirable a break after the equals sign.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, but I do not think it does what I want. I want the whole inline expression on the next line, and depending on the width of the splitable parts.

Comment: You're starting from a false assumption: $v_{initial}=$ is almost 40pt, so it can't be considered "small", being more than 10% of a standard line width.

Comment: @egreg Ok. But sometimes, you get the same behavior with inline math like `$1+1=2$`.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I don't think you need lua callbacks here:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\binoppenalty=\maxdimen
\relpenalty=\maxdimen
\emergencystretch=3em
A text with an inline equation which is broken in to two parts
but is not wanted right here $v_{initial} = 11111$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\relpenalty=10000` suffice? :)

Comment: yes but you might mis-type the number of 0s Better to whack it with a sledgehammer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/prevent-latex-to-break-an-inline-math-equation/94397#94397 :-)

Comment: Ok, but sometimes you do want a line break at `binop` and `relop`, when the inline math is wider than a simple `2 = 1 + 1`.

Comment: BTW, I tested the suggestion @egreg made in comment and no line break occurred. I must have done a silly mistake. Thanks for the `\maxdimen` trick.

Comment: @cjorssen 10000 is enough to prevent breaks , the default is 500 there are a lot of numbers in between which just discourage breaks with varying degrees of strength so that breaks are still allowed (eg if the expression is wider than textwidth) although even 9999 isn't enough to prevent the break in your example unless you make everything else even more sloppy than `\sloppy`