# Bad box because of algebraic expression

Tags: math-mode, boxes

I'm getting a bad box in the following (I can see in the PDF that the expression is shooting past the right edge of page contents):

```
\item If $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{e}{f} = \ldots$, then each of these ratios    
is equal to $\left( \dfrac {pa^n + qc^n + re^n + \ldots}{pb^n + qd^n + rf^n + \ldots} 
right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $p$, $q$, $r \ldots$ are any quantities whatsoever.
```

Is there an automatic setting that will shift the expressions to the next line? Or perhaps there's a better solution?

Comment: A self-contained an [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) would be helpful. But perhaps the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/) already solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use `\dfrac` in text mode, prefer the slahed form. A big fraction such as the one in the middle should probably be displayed. Use `\dotsb` instead of `\ldots` in the big fraction (after `+`) and `,\dotsc` in the last occurrence.

Comment: @egreg, but using only `\frac` makes the font smaller, which I don't want. Plus it doesn't solve the bad box problem.

Comment: Use `$a/b$`, not `$\frac{a}{b}$` inline. But the bad break is due to the big fraction that shouldn't be inline. If the original is bad, why trying to replicate it?

Comment: @egreg The original is a book from which I'm making notes. I was just wondering id there's a way to automatically insert a line break in case of a bad box.

Comment: @dotslash You could add `\sloppy` or set `\emergencystretch`; however this wouldn't help in improving quality, and probably they'd do worse.

Comment: Yeah ... I guess I'll have to live with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\sloppy` in front the expression to force a break, but that doesn't make it look any better:

[image]

That said, you can also add `\phantom{$\dfrac{a}{b}$}` at the end to force a "normal" looking vertical spacing, the full code reads:

```
\item If $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{e}{f} = \ldots$, then each of theseratios is equal to \sloppy\(\left( \dfrac {pa^n + qc^n + re^n + \ldots}{pb^n + qd^n + rf^n + \ldots}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\), where $p$, $q$, $r \ldots$ are any quantities whatsoever.\phantom{$\dfrac{a}{b}$}
```

and the result:

[image]

Still, I would suggest you to use display style for the big expression, as Peter Grill did.

Comment: As I predicted, the result is a disaster. `;-)`

Comment: I would think it is better to use `\frac` instead of `\dfrac` in this case.

Comment: Use `\frac` would make the space around fraction looks really weird as we used `\sloppy`... may be `a/b` would be slightly better.

Comment: @Francis Keep in mind that `\sloppy` is a declaration that will be in force from that point on. Either add `\fussy` or use grouping (and `\par` before the closing brace).

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend you use display math for the fraction:

[image]

## Notes:

- As per egreg's suggestion I have used `\dotsb` and `\dotsc`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item If $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{e}{f} = \dotsb$, then each of these ratios    
is equal to 
\[\left( \dfrac {pa^n + qc^n + re^n + \dotsb}{pb^n + qd^n + rf^n + \dotsb} 
\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}, \] 
where $p$, $q$, $r \dotsc$ are any quantities whatsoever.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that helps. Although I'd have preferred something closer to the original.

Comment: You missed changing one `\ldots` to `\dotsb` and there should be a comma after `r`.