# What command can I use to break the formula to have the alignment acceptable?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Below, in the image, there is a math formula which has a pink underline (namely `Ann_{f(A)+J}(J)=0`). As you see the alignment isn't acceptable (highlighted).
Question.  What command can I use to break the formula to have the alignment acceptable? I don't want to use break commands such as `\ \` (since the text or format will probably change).

[image]

Comment: Rewrite the text, plus Ann ought to be written on upright so it isn't confused with A times n times n.

Comment: yes "Ann ought to be written on upright", thanks. but there is no way other than "Rewrite the text"? may be it should be repeated several times.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In this particular case, I'd try removing *that* just before the formula. Doing `\DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann}` in the preamble and typing in the formula as `$\Ann_{f(A)+J}(J)=0$` might avoid the issue. Defining `\Ann` that way is recommended nonetheless.

Comment: thank you egreg. it is a good tip from an Experienced man to remove  *that*. but  writing "Ann" *upright* dont help

Comment: "and let" instead of "and assume that" is acceptable?

Comment: yes. thank you. in fact i want to know if there is a way that alignment automatically done by software?

Comment: You also might write `Theorem 2.5. Assume that …`

Comment: In special cases the automatic simple can not do it.  Then your action is needed. That means for example to rephrase ...  Your case seems to be a special one ...  BTW: have you called package `microtype`? If not please do it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish latex to linebreak BEFORE the inline equation so that the equation will not be broken.
In that case if you use { } to tell latex the formula is one atom: `${Ann_{f(A)+J}(J)=0)}$` and will not be broken.

see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/prevent-latex-to-break-an-inline-math-equation)

Comment: @Elad Den. thank you. my priority is "alignment ". So "\sloppy" in *Herbert*'s answer is close to answer. in fact using "\sloppy" is good but makes unwanted white places. But i wish  latex to use "linebreak" (BEFORE "=", for example) and then "shrink" to have a good alignment.

Comment: ah ! I see...
did you see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness) ?

Comment: Thank you very much  Elad Den. your links are very helpful. And Thank you for reading long comments