# How to not wrap equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, wrap, inline

While writing a paragraph of proof containing some (inline) short equations, some of them often wrap: half of the equation stays on the line 1 and the second part of the equation comes to line 2.

Is wrapping (short) equations considered sloppy in math writing?

If so, what is a universal way (not hard-code) to unwrap all equations?

A simple "line-change" or "newline" might work. However, this method has two major drawbacks because it is a hard-coding. First, I need to make a line-change for all equations. Second, after edit some other texts, the line-change will sometimes back-fire and I need to delete the line-change.

Comment: See `\relpenalty` and `\binoppenalty` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94397/73317) (assuming you are prepared to deal with the resulting overfull and underfull `\hbox`es...).

Comment: I assume you are talking inline math.  You can always put the equations into `\mbox{$...$}` but you will get ugly gaps in your text or run into the right margin instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes it is about inline math.

Comment: It isn't considered sloppy, don't worry. You might increase the value of `\binoppenalty` (default is 700) and of `\relpenalty` (default is 500). But this has drawbacks because TeX will  likely not be able to find good break points.